# When i run this code, i am am not getting any output when i punch in the available input

Tags: python, if-statement, input, boolean-logic

Here is a code to take boolean input in the form of 'H' & 'C' and print the output accordingly using if-else statement. When I run this code, I am able to enter the input but I am not getting any output after entering 'H' or 'C'. Where am I going wrong?

Error message: No error message.

Expected result:  On Entering 'H' - 'Its a hot day'; On Entering 'C' - 'Its a cold day'.

```py
H = True
C = False

print("Enter if it is a hot or cold day \n , H for Hot day, C for Cold day")

i = input('enter H or C \n')


if (i == H):
   print('Its a hot day')

elif (i == C):
   print('Its a cold day')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `H` and `C` as `True` and `False`. Then you are comparing the input (which should be either the string `"H"` or the string `"C"`) to these boolean values. They will never be equal. Instead, check if the input is either of these strings:

```py
H = "H"
C = "C"
print("Enter if it is a hot or cold day \n , H for Hot day, C for Cold day")
i = input('enter H or C \n')
if (i == H): 
  print('Its a hot day')
elif (i == C): 
  print('Its a cold day')
```